# On cases notation

Tags: reference-request, notation

In a formal situation, is it acceptable to write the statement "If $a\geqslant 1$ then $x>y$, if $-1\leqslant a<1$ then $x=y$, and if $a<-1$ then $x<y$." using cases notation as below?
$$x\begin{cases}
>y&\text{if }a\geqslant 1;\\
=y&\text{if }-1\leqslant a<1;\\
<y&\text{if }a<-1.\\
\end{cases}$$
Is anybody aware of a formal resource (books, papers) where such a notation is used?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "in a formal situation". I haven't seen anything like your proposed notation in the literature and think it would throw many readers. I'd suggest reformulating it as an equation (with cases on the r.h.s.) about $\mathrm{sgn}(x - y)$, so it looks like $\mathrm{sgn}(x - y) = \{ \vdots$.

Comment: It seems like you have something in mind you want to express in notation. I don't think this question is really easy to answer beyond "No" as it stands now - what exactly are you trying to do with this notation? If you had to write out verbosely what you want to say with some minimal context, what would you write?

Answer (score 2):

It is an easy fix. The following is much easier to read:
$$\begin{cases}
x>y&\text{if }a\geqslant 1;\\
x=y&\text{if }-1\leqslant a<1;\\
x<y&\text{if }a<-1.\\
\end{cases}$$

Coming to think about it, the brace is not really needed. So you should just use the align environment

$$\begin{align}
x>y&\quad \text{ if }a\geqslant 1;\\
x=y&\quad \text{ if }-1\leqslant a<1;\\
x<y&\quad \text{ if }a<-1.\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: I've not seen these notations either. The first seems likely to be objectionable unless you're in a context where it's okay to treat $x>y$ as an expression. The second is clearer, but I would parse it as a table (which suggests the author should format such a thing as, well, a table rather than as a single math environment)